# Combining multiple .java files into one .jar file (they are dependent of each other) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Here's the deal. I'm fairly new to Java and I have these three .java files that I need to compile into one .jar executable.

1. ho.java
2. read.java
3. write.java

Each file has it's own JFrame and the thing is I need to make an action in ho.java open the JFrame in read.java and another action in ho.java open the JFrame of write.java.

In eclipse, how would I go about doing this? I've seen topics where people want to know how to combine multiple jar files into one, but I wonder how to compile multiple .java files into one .jar file.

If it's impossible, then how should I interconnect these three files?

Comment: You mean .class files right?

Comment: file-->export--->java----->extract into jar------>try the jar if it works, if it doesnt, put the necessary dll files near that jar.

Comment: You can try `Right Click your Project -> Export`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can export them.

In the package explorer, select all of the necessary java files wit Ctrl+click, right-click the selection, and select "export"

[image]

Continue through the wizard, selecting Runnable Jar file or Jar File to your liking, select the export directory, and finish. You are done.

However, if you selected to export the ant buildfile, you can reuse it with a builder. Right-click your project, and select properties.

[image]

Under "builders", add a new builder as shown here:

[image]

Its type should be an ANT builder.

For the buildfile, select browse workspace or browse filesystem(depending on where you exported it) and select the .xml file you exported previously. You can now do Project->Build and your Ant build will occur as part of the build process.

Answer (score 2):

If they are in the same project, then you can simply right click on your project in the popumenu select `Export...`

In the following Dialog you go to `Java -> Runnable JAR File`

Answer (score 0):

Put all your files in a folder in your Eclipse project and then:

> 1. Right click in your folder
> 2. Export
> 3. Java -> Runnable JAR File